# Updating a field in firebase (db) from the client's perspective

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I've been working with firebase and I am trying to update a field in my firebase db based on the inputs from a client. I want a block of plain text to sync/update the database when changed to effectively save the work in the event of a browser crash.

I have read over the firebase REST API but I just don't get it, these commands look like/are command line commands not something that looks like it would belong in the function body of an onclick:

```
$(#submit_button).click(function() {
   /* REST API PUT command */
   curl -X PUT -d '{ "articleName": "New Title", "body": "edited body..." }' \
   https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/article.json
}
```

What am I missing? It seems like the act of a client changing a data base via a request happens all the time. Thanks

Comment: Turns out I was over-thinking the whole thing. Was used to using firebase as a node module (server-side only) and that was causing all the confusion. All I had to do was include the cdn to firebase.js below and then use it as normal, took me a while to figure this out.

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.11/firebase.js'></script>
    //then you can
    var db = new Firebase(<your fb url>)
    //in your index.js or wherever

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't use the REST API from JavaScript, you'd just need to make an HTTP call (ie, $.ajax or XMLHttpRequest, etc)

Comment: Hello AuthorOfTheSurf. Thanks for telling us how you solved the problem. Here at StackOverflow, we don't like keeping questions without answers. Since you discovered the solution yourself, you can either provide that as an answer and exception or alternatively we can close the question as "not likely to help others". Any preference?

Comment: Let's close it, thanks.